# Converting Lyx to Word

Tags: pandoc, export, convert, doc

I am using Lyx2.3.3. I have installed Pandoc. I reconfigured Lyx ( Tools> reconfigure). I should then be able to simply export lyx file to the MS Word Office open XML, however I get an error as shown in the next image.[image: Lyx to Word export issue]

Any suggestion?

Comment: switch the filenames.

Comment: @naphaneal , I did not get your point.

Comment: you're converting from a `*.docx` to a `*.tex`.

Comment: @naphaneal, no the opposite, from Lyx to Word

Comment: not according to the error message and the manual. in your case, the source is the `*.docx` and the target is the `*.tex`.

Comment: No dear , look at the logo, I am on Lyx

Comment: It's better to convert to `.odt` by using `TeX4ht`...

Comment: @naphaneal You are reading erroneously the error message. The order of files is misleading as human being expect a source-output order, but here the output  (`-o`) is the first file, and therefore the source from (`-f`) latex that should be exported to  (`-t`) docx format is the last file (that is the mandatory argument, not an option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer at the subheading "***Try exporting a LyX document***" at this web-page
https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/ExportingOpenDocumentLibreofficeOpenofficeAndOfficeOpenXMLMSWordWithPandoc

If not all goes well, you will see a warning box with a message like

> "Error while running pandoc -s -f latex -o $$o -t docx $$i"

That's most likely because LyX is not sending Pandoc a file with the proper encoding. For a quick fix try: `Document > Settings`, go to the `Language section`, and under `Encoding` select `Other: Unicode (utf8)`. Try exporting again.

If that works now, then encoding was the problem. See the `Troubleshooting section` for a way to ensure that all your new `LyX` documents have the proper encoding setting. If you still get the warning message, see Troubleshooting below.